# How to turn a column of timestamps into two columns depending on separate column without splitting rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that has a column for timestamps and another column that has statuses. I want to grab the timestamp when the status is checked-in as well as the timestamp when it is completed into one row. When I try to use a case statement I end up with it split into two rows. I am wanting it to return one row with the values in each timestamp column rather than two rows one for each with the null in the other.

```
CASE WHEN aud.STATUS_DESCRIPTION = 'CHECKED_IN' THEN aud.STATUS_DATETIME
END AS "Check-In Time",
CASE WHEN aud.STATUS_DESCRIPTION = 'COMPLETED' THEN aud.STATUS_DATETIME 
END AS "Completed Time",
```

[Table with statuses and timestamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ9Zg.png) 
[What my case statement is returning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sMT6.png)

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with self-join.

```
SELECT 
    chcecked.STATUS_DATETIME as CHECKED_IN_TIME,
    completed.STATUS_DATETIME as COMPLETED_TIME
FROM
    yourtable as checked
JOIN
    yourtable as completed
ON ....
```

Comment: This is how I ended up getting it to worked. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because your data is across many rows.

You ether need to do some form of aggregation, so [GROUP BY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/group-by.html) and then using an aggregate function like [MIN/MAX](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min.html)

OR You need to classify the data you want, and then use a [PIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html) to do the aggregation for you.

The first might look like:

```
SELECT 
    some_column_a,
    some_column_b,
    MAX(IFF( aud.status_description = 'CHECKED_IN', aud.status_datetime, null)) as check_in_time
    MAX(IFF( aud.status_description = 'COMPLETED', aud.status_datetime, null)) as complete_time
FROM table  
GROUP BY some_column_a, some_column_b
ORDER BY some_column_a, some_column_b;
```

So adding a working example

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT to_date(column1) as STATUS_DATETIME,
        column2 as STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
        column3 as customer_id
    FROM VALUES
        ('2021-12-11 11:12:03','CREATED', 1),
        ('2021-12-11 11:12:03','CHECKED_IN', 1),
        ('2021-12-11 11:22:49','PROGRESS', 1),
        ('2021-12-11 11:55:03','COMPLETED', 1),
        ('2021-10-11 11:55:03','COMPLETED', 0)
)
SELECT 
    aud.customer_id,
    MAX(IFF( aud.status_description = 'CHECKED_IN', aud.status_datetime, null)) as check_in_time,
    MAX(IFF( aud.status_description = 'COMPLETED', aud.status_datetime, null)) as complete_time
FROM data as aud 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

This example works well if you have many `customer_id`'s and many entries per customer_id. If how every your table size is small, and you never have two records in the "completed" state then the join can work.

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT to_date(column1) as STATUS_DATETIME,
        column2 as STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
        column3 as customer_id
    FROM VALUES
        ('2021-12-11 11:12:03','CREATED', 1),
        ('2021-12-11 11:12:03','CHECKED_IN', 1),
        ('2021-12-11 11:22:49','PROGRESS', 1),
        ('2021-12-11 11:55:03','COMPLETED', 1),
        ('2021-10-11 11:55:03','COMPLETED', 0)
)
SELECT 
    checked.customer_id,  
    checked.status_datetime as check_in_time,
    completed.status_datetime as complete_time
FROM data as checked
JOIN data as completed
    ON checked.customer_id = completed.customer_id
        AND checked.STATUS_DESCRIPTION = 'CHECKED_IN'
        AND completed.STATUS_DESCRIPTION = 'COMPLETED'
;
```

The place the join does not work is if you do not have both "completed" and "checked_in". For the above SQL there is no row for customer_id `0`. Because there is only one

So for that you need a full outer join, and then it makes sense to move the filters to a CTE (or sub select), like so:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT to_date(column1) as STATUS_DATETIME,
        column2 as STATUS_DESCRIPTION,
        column3 as customer_id
    FROM VALUES
        ('2021-12-11 11:12:03','CREATED', 1),
        ('2021-12-11 11:12:03','CHECKED_IN', 1),
        ('2021-12-11 11:22:49','PROGRESS', 1),
        ('2021-12-11 11:55:03','COMPLETED', 1),
        ('2021-10-11 11:55:03','COMPLETED', 0)
), completed_data AS (
    SELECT STATUS_DATETIME, STATUS_DESCRIPTION, customer_id
    FROM data
    WHERE STATUS_DESCRIPTION = 'COMPLETED'
), checked_in_data AS (
    SELECT STATUS_DATETIME, STATUS_DESCRIPTION, customer_id
    FROM data
    WHERE STATUS_DESCRIPTION = 'CHECKED_IN'
)
SELECT 
    COALESCE(checked.customer_id, completed.customer_id) AS customer_id,
    checked.status_datetime as check_in_time,
    completed.status_datetime as complete_time
FROM checked_in_data as checked
FULL OUTER JOIN completed_data as completed
    ON checked.customer_id = completed.customer_id
ORDER BY 1,2;
;
```

which gives the output:

| CUSTOMER_ID | CHECK_IN_TIME | COMPLETE_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | 2021-10-11 |
| 1 | 2021-12-11 | 2021-12-11 |

Comment: I appreciate the input, I have tried the former suggestion and it still returns the same result so I will look into using a pivot.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an example of how to use `pivot` which is an addition to Simeon's answer.Using sample data from the image provided.

Table creation and data insertion:

```
create or replace temporary table _temp (
  ts timestamp_ntz,
  _status varchar
);

insert into _temp
values ('2021-12-11 11:12:03','created'),
('2021-12-11 11:12:03','checked_in'),
('2021-12-11 11:22:49','progress'),
('2021-12-11 11:55:03','completed');
```

Pivot query:

```
select *
from _temp
pivot(max(ts) for _status in ('checked_in', 'completed')) as p;
```

Result:

```
'checked_in'                  'completed'
2021-12-11 11:12:03.000    2021-12-11 11:55:03.000
```

Note that I've used `MAX` aggregate function which can be replaced by other aggregate functions. This would always return a single row if there are only 2 columns, to get a better sense of pivot have another column and take a look at examples provided in Pivot's doc.

Comment: I tried the pivot but then it was giving me 3 rows, I ended up getting it with a self join where the status was checked in and again when it was completed. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: Hi @Ryan_Chavez i've tried using the data provided by you and the result is:
'checked_in' 'completed'
2021-12-11 11:12:03.000 2021-12-11 11:55:03.000
Am I missing something here?